# Inverse of an $L^\infty$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Suppose that $A(\underline{x})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a **positive-definite** matrix whose entries $A_{ij}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open domain, $n>1$.

Is it true that the inverse $A^{-1}(\underline{x})$ also has elements in $L^\infty(\Omega)$? How to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Is false even if $n=1$: $A(x)={1\over x^2+1}$.

Comment: But if $\Omega$ is also bounded...?

Comment: In the bounded interval (0,1) you have simply $A(x)=x$.